# How to initialize the Sound class in Python

Tags: python, audio

I am trying to set a Speaker's sound using a Python script and I was able to find that this should be done by assigning to the `data.sound` attribute of the Speaker object instance.

I also found that the appropriate value type for the attribute is [`Sound`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Sound.html), however I have trouble instantiating it. From the documentation it looks like it has a constructor which takes an ID. When passing an empty string, I get a confusing error:

```
sound = pby.types.Sound('')
```

> TypeError: bpy_struct.**new**(type): type 'Sound' is not a subtype of bpy_struct

The documentation would have you believe `Sound` indeed is a subtype of `bpy_struct`, because that's what it says in the base classes line.

However, clicking further through to [`bpy_struct`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html), one finds this note:

> Note that bpy.types.bpy_struct is not actually available from within Blender, it only exists for the purpose of documentation.

Blender seems to be well aware of it though as it throws an error at me for not instantiating a correct subclass of it.

What gives? How come Blender is aware of this type and how come `Sound` is not a proper subclass of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Blender very rarely (if at all) instances from class.**

Rather than add a new object with  `ob = bpy.types.Object("blah")` the blender way is to use the `new` method, or for images and sounds the `load` method of its data collection. eg `bpy.data.objects.new("name", data)` or `bpy.data.sounds.load(filepath)`

To load a new sound

```
snd = bpy.data.sounds.load("/path/to/soundfile")
```

python console, add a speaker and add sound.

```
>>> D.speakers.new(
new()
BlendDataSpeakers.new(name)
Add a new speaker to the main database
>>> D.speakers.new("xxx")
bpy.data.speakers['xxx']

>>> D.speakers['xxx'].sound = D.sounds.load(
load()
BlendDataSounds.load(filepath, check_existing=False)
Add a new sound to the main database from a file
>>> D.speakers['xxx'].sound = D.sounds.load("/tmp/xxx.mp3")
>>>  speaker_obj = bpy.data.objects.new("speaker", D.speakers['xxx'])
```

Link to scene in 2.79 and prior

```
>>> C.scene.objects.link(speaker_obj)
```

Alternatively with the operator, Add a new speaker object to the scene

```
bpy.ops.object.speaker_add(view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0), rotation=(0, 0, 0))
speaker_obj = context.object
```